# How do I convert a variable to float?

Tags: python

```
numbers = []

while(True):
    num = input("Enter a number or press Enter to stop :")
    if num:
        numbers.append(int(num))
    elif(num == ''):
            break
sum_num =0
for num in numbers:
    sum_num += num
avg = sum_num / len(numbers)
print("The sum is",sum_num)
print("The average is", avg)
```

The average is in decimal format, however, the sum is not.

```
The sum is 6
The average is 2.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried `print(float(sum_num))`? `/` converts `avg` to decimal but if you're summing ints, you're guaranteed an int. Why would you want that to be a decimal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `sum_num` a float in the beginning already, use:

```
sum_num = 0.0
```

Then appending integers to a float will still retain the float format.

Example:

```
>>> sum_num = 0.0
>>> sum_num += 1
>>> sum_num
1.0
>>>
```

Or you could use:

```
print("The sum is", float(sum_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

On your code, `int(num)` returns interger value. Therefore, change the code

```
    if num:
    numbers.append(int(num))
```

to

```
if num:
    numbers.append(float(num))
```